# "For a person whose past,present and future are the same" from Dhammapada

Tags: pali-canon, rebirth, zen, free-will, laws

With reference to the title of the question, I would like to know if the person blessed or under a curse if for him the past, present, and future are the same?

If by unlawful acts he is elevated to a higher position when these three positions are better. He wants such a condition to perpetuate and go on.

If he is downgraded for his lawful acts, his downfall is usually bitter for him.

How to analyze the situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dhammapada verse 421 does not say: "*for him the past, present and future are the same*".

The Pali is:

> Yassa (whatever) pure (past) ca (and) pacchā (future) ca (and), majjhe
> (middle) ca  natthi (does not exist) kiñcanaṃ (in any way) akiñcanaṃ
> (not in anyway) anādānaṃ (not grasping)
>
> He who clings to nothing of the past, present and future, who has no attachment and holds on to nothing — him do I call a holy man. (Buddharakkhita)
>
> He who has nothing
> — in front, behind, in between —
> the one with nothing
> who clings to no thing:
> he's what I call
> a brahman. (Thanissaro)
>
> For whom there is nothing in the past, the future or the present,
> having nothing and unattached, that one I say is a brahmin. (Anandajoti)